# Is this possible with Visual Studio snippets?

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, code-snippets

I use a modified form of TODO comment (SteveC_TODO) that allows me to group my own todos together in the task list.

Yesterday I thought it would be nice to modify the refactoring snippets to add a todo comment to the usual NotImplemented exception. I modified the Method Stub - Body snippet to this

```
$signature$
{
  //SteveC_TODO: implement $end$$signature$
  throw new $Exception$();
}
```

but this results in the todo comment having the full method signature. It serves the purpose but I would prefer the comment to only use the name from the method signature and be of the form

```
//SteveC_TODO: implement CoolMethod
```

rather than of the form

```
//SteveC_TODO: implement private void CoolMethod(object o)
```

Does anyone know of a way that I can do this? I presume that the arguments passed to refactoring snippets are fixed but perhaps there is a way to parse the $signature$ argument to extract just the name. Anyone know if that might be possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to modify it to something like

```
$accessability$ $returntype$ $method$($arguments$) 
{
   //SteveC_TODO: implement $method$
   $end$throw new $Exception$("The method or operation is not implemented.");
}
```

You have to declare the literals accessability, returntype, method, arguments,...

Have a look here for [how to create codesnippets](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-visual-studio-code-snippets)

Comment: As I expected that doesn't work. The refactoring code that calls the snippet expects it to have a $signature$ token.