# Changing the "generate field stub..." default behaviour in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2013, code-snippets

I'd like to change the default behavior of Visual Studio's "Generate field stub for..." feature. I already know about the folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring
```

But the field stub snippet here only has $signature$, which I assume is used as a placeholder for some IDE hocus-pocus. This hocus-pocus is precisely what I need to modify.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can be done: see previously asked questions:

> [Generate method stub snippet: Alter signature to make access level public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569836/generate-method-stub-snippet-alter-signature-to-make-access-level-public)
>
> [Is this possible with Visual Studio snippets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949825/is-this-possible-with-visual-studio-snippets)
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710181/change-visual-studio-refactoring-code-snippets-methodbodystub-adding-default

Incidentally, the `Generate Field.snippet` stub in my folder:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring

is

```
<Code Language="csharp">
  <![CDATA[$end$$accessibility$ $modifiers$ $type$ $signature$;]]>
</Code>
```

and not just `$signature$`.

My apologies :\